# Bash errors PS1 and git completion

Tags: git, bash, command-line

I tried following the tutorial @ https://github.com/bobthecow/git-flow-completion/wiki/Install-Bash-git-completion

here is my ~/.bash_profile :

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"

alias subl="/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl"


alias gl="git log --all --oneline --decorate --graph --pretty=format:'%h - %C(cyan)%an%Creset, %Cred%d%Creset %C(yellow)%ar%Creset : %s'"

if [ -f `brew --prefix`/etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . `brew --prefix`/etc/bash_completion
fi

if [ -f $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion ]; then
  GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE=true
  GIT_PS1_SHOWUNTRACKEDFILES=true
  #PS1='\u: \W$(__git_ps1 "[%s]") \$ '
  PS1='\[\e[32m\]\u: \W$(__git_ps1 "[%s]") \$\[\e[m\] '
fi
```

The errors I get when I open terminal:

```
-bash:     .: command not found
-bash:   GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE=true: command not found
-bash:   GIT_PS1_SHOWUNTRACKEDFILES=true: command not found
-bash:   #PS1=\u: \W$(__git_ps1 "[%s]") \$ : command not found
-bash:   PS1=\[\e[32m\]\u: \W$(__git_ps1 "[%s]") \$\[\e[m\] : command not found
```

I want my PS1 to look something like

```
(user name): (current directory)(current repo branch *status*) $:
```

Thanks any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compare the output from entering a bogus command at the shell manually:

```
$ felkj
-bash: felkj: command not found
```

to the output you are getting from your script:

```
-bash:     .: command not found
-bash:   GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE=true: command not found
-bash:   GIT_PS1_SHOWUNTRACKEDFILES=true: command not found
-bash:   #PS1=\u: \W$(__git_ps1 "[%s]") \$ : command not found
-bash:   PS1=\[\e[32m\]\u: \W$(__git_ps1 "[%s]") \$\[\e[m\] : command not found
```

See the extra spaces after `-bash:`? That's your problem.

Somehow you managed to get non-ascii spaces into your script files. Edit them again and make sure to use ascii spaces on those lines instead of 'EN SPACE' (U+2002).

Comment: Sorry, relatively new to command line, where are the extra spaces in the code for the bash profile?